# main() does not terminate after successful pthread_join

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I have a program that starts a pthread and later on waits for the termination of this thread before it returns. The code is something like:

```c
int main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
  pthread_t t;
  /* initialization and other stuff 
     ... 
  */
  printf("join result:%d\n", pthread_join(t, 0));
  return 0;
}
```

The program prints, as it is supposed to: `join result: 0`. So the join works and *t* is finished. Nevertheless the program does not stop execution. I can only force it to stop if I insert a command `exit(0)` (or some other number) before the `return 0` line.

**However**, if I remove the line with the `pthread_join` call the program exits flawlessly.

How is this even possible? What could keep a program from finishing execution after all sub-threads are joined?

**EDIT:** I just found out that gdb tells me  I get a segmentation fault after the execution of the last line with `}`. Nevertheless I have no idea what is going on behind the scenes:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000060003aa10 in ?? ()
```

Comment: I was checking out the man page and came across this:        
       
     If multiple threads simultaneously try to join with the same thread,
     the results are undefined.  If the thread calling pthread_join() is
     canceled, then the target thread will remain joinable (i.e., it will
     not be detached).

Any chance you are doing something like that?

Comment: @RobertEkendahl But would that not be reflected in the message of `printf`? Either way I have only one main thread which creates and joins other threads.

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for why you would get a segfault. Can you post some more of the code?

Comment: @RobertEkendahl I'll try to reduce the code to the reduce the code to the bare minimum and will post it soon.

Comment: I think it may be possible that a stack corruption occurs in the main thread. From windows i know that before executing main, the adress of the exit_process function is pushed onto the stack. Then return 0 performs an exit_process call. If in your case the stack was corrupted, it's possible the pointer to exit_process was replaced with an invalid pointer.

Comment: I think that might have been the problem! I used GMP for arbitrary precision arithmetic and forgot to initialize a GMP variable before using it for calculations.

Comment: The standard checks: Does the code compile without warnings if compiled with all warnings on `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Does it run without errors under a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.com)?

Comment: @GeoAoe If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it because it was the ultimate reason of my problem (as commented before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be possible that a **stack corruption** occurs in the main thread. From windows i know that before executing main, the adress of the exit_process function is pushed onto the stack. Then return 0 performs an exit_process call. If in your case the stack was corrupted, it's possible the pointer to exit_process was replaced with an invalid pointer.